# Why do my custom activities just sit on a greyed-out loading screen when I try to view them in Journey Builder?

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, custom-activity

I have built two different custom activities and hosted them on two different hosting platforms and both of them view fine when I load them in the browser, but when I add them to a journey and click on them to make edits, I can see the interface faded out with a loading wheel in front. It does not seem to ever finish loading. Is there a setting I am missing? Obviously the app package is "seeing" the code as I can see my interface loaded in the background...

Where it has happened with two different apps and two different hosting servers (Heroku and Siteground), I have to assume I am missing something in SFMC itself... but the set up there is pretty straightforward and I haven't found anything online to identify anywhere I may have gone wrong...

Comment: Welcome to Salesforce Stack Exchange (SFSE). I am unfamiliar with SFMC & Journeys. Is there any config or custom code that you think might even tangentially be related that you can share? If so, please [edit](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/posts/357066/edit) your question to include it. More info is (usually) better than not enough when trying to get folks to help.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Make sure you configured a Data Source to the journey (i.e. data extension or something else).